# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.title')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I followed the React Navigation Doc to achieve a [Dynamic header title change](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/) but It shows the error Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.title').

My tabs.js:

```
function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.title })}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

The Home.js has the onpress like that:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('Profile', {
      title: 'Custom title',
    });
  }}
>
```

And Profile.js:

```
function Profile({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Hello</Text>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you `setOption` the title?

Comment: No, I should only use that inside the Profile screen if I wanted to change the title on button press right? I want to just navigate to Profile and pass the profile name as the header title... @NishargShah

Comment: use expo snack to create the snippet, so I can help you easily

Answer (score 0):

Add a check/default value on your params, because route.params is not always valorized, but only when you navigate on that page.

```
function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <HomeStack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params?.title || "DEFAULT TITLE" })}
      />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```